# Using cURL through SSH tunnel or VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, tunnel, curl

I would like to set my CURL to use SSH tunneling for certain domains. How can I accomplish that? I can also set up VPN or SOCKS or whatever, but I need to use CURL on local machine, but use the IP of remote machine for those connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenSSH can create a SOCKS proxy with the `-D` option, and cURL can use a SOCKS proxy with the various `--socks*` options.